# How to sensibly block I.P addresses and detect spammers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security

This is more of a general question. I am aware it is possible to block IP addresses by updating the Nginx configuration.

See: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/

My question is how do Rails programmers detect spam?

I use Recaptcha but recently found out someone was still able to register. At least 50 signups for same IP.

```
before_filter :block_users

private

def block_users
  if @current_ip and  @blocked_ips.include?(@current_ip)
    redirect_to "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_a_life"
  end
end
```

Is there is anything more sensible than blocking an IP address?

Comment: If you registered everybody from my company, we'd all appear to be using the same IP address.

Comment: Spams are mostly automated, so I added a hidden checkbox to my comment form. If it's a real user the checkbox remains unchecked. I disregard any submissions where the hidden checkbox is checked. Haven't had any spam since. (Knocking on wood)

Comment: @mischa https://github.com/subwindow/negative-captcha seems to do what you are doing in a much better way

Comment: @Rubish, thanks. Looks very interesting. I will probably use that instead of implementing something myself next time.